# NSIS pcre unicode

Tags: unicode, installation, nsis, pcre

The documentation to the PCRE NSIS plugin states it has some support for unicode regex's.

When writing my regular expression it works with a non unicode NSIS instance but not with the NSIS unicode installer.

Is there anything special which must be done in order to parse unicode encoded strings through PCRE on unicode nsis?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin seems to support searching in utf-8 text, but it not a plugin supporting the unicode version of NSIS.

Its source code should be upgraded / ported to Unicode NSIS.

Comment: I looked on the unicode NSIS site but there seems to be no reference to NSISPcre unicode plugin. Have you ever seen a unicode version?

Comment: @user204088 [NSISpcre bin](https://github.com/mazinsw/NSISpcre/tree/master/bin)